# Can't find Krita in Start Menu (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux-mint

I installed [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) through Linux Mint Software Manager.

Software Manager shows Krita as installed, but when I open the Start menu, and type Krita, nothing shows.

I've searched the hard drive and see a folder /usr/share/kde4/apps/krita but don't see any way to start Krita from inside this folder.

Comment: Did it work if you start it from the terminal ?

Comment: what is the output of `whereis krita` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it.

Right click on the Menu icon.

Click on "Configure".

Click on "Menu".

Click on "Open the menu editor".

Click on "Graphics".

Right click on the Krita icon.

Click on "Properties".

Make sure that the Command box reads "/usr/bin/krita %u". If not, correct it.